# Novel about a human visiting a colonised planet where the natives are like humans with tails

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-colonization

There is a human from another long-colonized planet, visiting. He sees only female natives, who are being exploited. He finds the hidden males and discovers that they are human, descendants of a crashed space ship from his planet. On his planet, many people have a gene for a tail, which is removed soon after birth. Written in English, maybe in the '50's to '80s from the style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly "*[The Lani People](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11486)*" by [Jesse F Bone](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1107).

In this story, a recently graduated vet is employed by a mysterious company at a very good rate to work on their "farm". When he arrives at the heavily defended and remote island farm, he finds that the animals (Lani) he is contracted to work on are very heavily humanoid, down to the genitalia. The vet thinks they are human, but the owner disputes this insisting that they are infertile with humans and that their previous (long term) vet had made especial study of this, as had the founder of the company. One defining characteristic of the differences is a long tail, which are often docked. The Lani are capable (one works as the vet's assistant), intelligent, learn a spoken language (without teaching from humans - passed down from their parents), and to all intents and purposes are sentient. However, the family that owns them has put this in front of a court and they were ruled to be animals.

The Lani that the vet works on are being sold as slave workers/animals to serve rich families as servants. During his work, the vet battles a disease in the Lani, which previously has only been seen in humans, and artificially inseminates them to produce more Lani, despite only seeing females as his patients. He works out that the males must be kept elsewhere by looking at the insemination fluid under a microscope and finding that it contains normal sperm. He is then taken to another very highly secure facility on another island where the (bred to be) highly aggressive males are kept, so that he can urgently treat one which has come down with a highly transmissible illness.

He falls in love with his Lani assistant (named Copper) and soon learns that she is pregnant with his child. He also finds out that the Lani have a ritual where they recite something passed down orally from their ancestors that is very similar to a known religious rite (think Mass in a church sort of thing), and deduces that they must be humans from an early colonization attempt, and that the spaceship must be nearby in a radioactive crater on the island. This means the Lani are humans, with a genetic mutation to produce tails, probably as a result of radiation and effectively enslaved, breaking interstellar law. He then sets out to prove this, but to do so he needs to get pregnant Copper off the planet to a safe haven as proof, and realizes the family firm will work to prevent this.

As a trained person he is able to fix up the ship, which works on a highly radioactive process and is called a "[spindizzy drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_in_Flight#Spindizzy)". He takes off with Copper, escaping the farm and takes her to his home planet, where a proportion of the people are also born with tails due to a genetic mutation caused by radiation exposure in their founding population, and is the reason he is cross-fertile with Copper.

Read for free at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2509)

Comment: That is it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JudithJones You are welcome. As you think this is the correct answer, please mark as accepted by clicking the check/tick below the voting arrows.