# 1980s serialized novel in Analog about an alien planet named something like Midanoa

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, planets

This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276123/novel-about-a-human-visiting-a-colonised-planet-where-the-natives-are-like-human/276146#276146) made me think of a novel from Analog that I read part of in the 1980s.  There's an alien planet being colonized by humans; the inhabitants are humanoid but fur-covered. The aliens call the planet something like "Midanoa." The key revelation is the discovery that

> The aliens are actually humans - a small ship crashed on the planet centuries earlier and the founder effect and genetic drift have led to a population that is very furry by average human standards (but not quite outside the range of observed human variation).  "Midanoa" is a garbling of "Middle of Nowhere" - which is where the crashed survivors were, as far as they were concerned.

Comment: At some cost to my sanity I have been through the contents pages of all editions of Analog from 1980 to 1990 inclusive looking at the serialised novels. However none match your description. The closest is Harry Turtledove's _Report on Bilbeis IV_ as that has anthropologists studying a planet of humanoids, but humanoids are not furry and I don't think they call the planet anything like _Midanoa_.

Comment: Thank you . I suppose it could be from the 70s, but save your sanity and don't check now

Comment: @JohnRennie "The Report on Bilbeis IV" is the last 2/3 of *Noninterference*; it's definitely not a match for the story.  (The humans aren't colonists, they're sociologists, xenologists, linguists, etc. and the aliens are human-like enough to only have hair on their heads.  Which is actually a minor plot point.)

Comment: FWIW, I also trolled through the 1980s, looking also in *F&SF* and *Asimov's* and right now I'm halfway through the 1970s.  How certain are you that it's in *Analog*?  I only have a few years left in the 1970s.  Might it have been in the 1990s?

Comment: @DavidW I went through the serialised novels in the 1970s Analogs and found no matches.

Comment: Pretty sure its Analog - but maybe it was a novella and not a serial. I have a faint association in my mind with Stan Schmidt, but that may be because he was the editor not the author

Comment: Okay, I've run through 1970-1993 *Analog*, *IASFM*, *F&SF*, *Amazing*, *Galaxy*, *Fantastic*, and *If* and even looked briefly at *Galileo*, *Aboriginal*, and *Interzone*.  No luck so far on matching serials; there are a couple in *Analog* I haven't actually re-read yet (I still need to find the issues) but the titles aren't promising.  (For example, *Minotaur in a Mushroom Maze*, Nancy & Richard Carrigan, May 1976ff.)